# Stringify JSON removing "$id" and "$values" properties

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string Json that comes from my backend that I'm trying to beatify it to show to the users, so I'm using the stringify to do this, but it keeps the "$id" and the "$value" to it, there is a way to remove it?

The code that I have is this:

`let jsonFormated = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(result.Value), null, '\t');`

the result.value came from the API that I'm calling, the value is a string that was serialized on the c# backend.

the result of it is this:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "$values": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "prop1": "result",
            "prop2": "result",
            "prop3": {
                "$id": "3",
                "$values": [
                    {
                        "$id": "4",
                        "prop1": "result",
                        "prop2": null
                    },
                    {
                        "$id": "4",
                        "prop1": "result",
                        "prop2": null
                    },
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to remove this properties "$id", "$values" and have only a structure equals that I recieved from the backend, but pretty printed, the structure that I recieve from the backend is that:

```
[{"prop1":"result","prop2":"result","prop3":[{"prop1":"result","prop2":"result"},{"prop1":"result","prop2":"result"}]}]
```

My problem is that I need it to be a string that I will send to a component, so I need the string to be correct

Comment: Remove them *before* stringifying.

Comment: If you only want to remove them when displaying, parse the JSON, remove the properties, and display that.

Comment: If you remove all properties that begin with `$`, you'll remove the entire `$values` property, and there won't be anything to display.

Comment: It looks like you want to replace each object that has `$id` and `$values` properties with just the contents of the `$values` array. You'll need to write a recursive function that implements this.

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively sanitize the properties from the json:

```js
function sanitizeJson(obj) {
  // Object is an array? Then recursively sanitize each element
  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj.map(sanitizeJson);
  }
  // Object is a non-null object
  else if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null) {
    // Both '$id' and '$values' properties exist? Sanitize the '$values' property
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('$id') && obj.hasOwnProperty('$values')) {
      return sanitizeJson(obj['$values']);
    }
    // Make a new object from the '$id' property and sanitize the remaining properties
    return Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(obj)
        .filter(([key]) => key !== '$id')
        .map(([key, value]) => [key, sanitizeJson(value)])
    );
  }
  return obj;
}

const json = '{"$id":"1","$values":[{"$id":"2","prop1":"result","prop2":"result","prop3":{"$id":"3","$values":[{"$id":"4","prop1":"result","prop2":null},{"$id":"4","prop1":"result","prop2":null}]}}]}';
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(json);
const result = JSON.stringify(sanitizeJson(jsonObject), null, '\t');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#using_the_reviver_parameter) and [`JSON.stringify` replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter) can be used to modify nested values :

```js
const obj = {"$id":"1","$values":[{"$id":"2","prop1":"result","prop2":"result","prop3":{"$id":"3","$values":[{"$id":"4","prop1":"result","prop2":null},{"$id":"4","prop1":"result","prop2":null}]}}]};

const json = JSON.stringify(obj, (k, v) => k == '$id' ? void 0 : v?.$values ?? v, 4);

console.log( json );
```